# Unable to create .txt file in C++ after string manipulation

Tags: c++, string, file, file-handling, string-concatenation

I am writing a program where I am expecting a symbol at the end of the string. I try to remove the symbol and adjust the string. Then I am trying to use that string as a filename to create a file. Before that, I add .txt to it as an extension. I have tried outputting the filename after that and it is a printed file. when I try to create a file the file is created and data is written on it fine. But the extension is not .txt. It's simply a "File". I can't figure out why it is not .txt. I think the problem might be related to setting '\0' manually. but if it is, then how the string concatenation is working fine?. please guide me through.
Here is the code:

```
 string str;
        cin >> str;
        if(str[str.size() - 1] == ',')
        {
            str[str.size() - 1] = '\0';
        }
        str+=".txt";
        ofstream file;
        file.open(str);
        file<<"Hello World";
        file.close();
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize

Comment: Resize the string, or [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) the character.

Comment: Also be careful to handle input-failure, as then the size of the string will be zero.

Comment: `str[str.size() - 1] = '\0'` doesn't change the internal size of the string, so using `+=` after that adds to the end of the string, after the 0. Try `str.pop_back();` or any of the other methods to remove tha last character that are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the character `','` to `'\0'` does not change the length of the string `str`

```
if(str[str.size() - 1] == ',')
{
    str[str.size() - 1] = '\0';
}
```

and the member function `append` used implicitly in this statement

```
str+=".txt";
```

appends the character literal `".txt"` to the preceding character `'\0'` keeping it as is.

However in the call of the method `open`

```
file.open(str);
```

the string is read as a C-string until the terminating zero character `'\0'` is encountered.

Instead you could write for example

```
    if( str.back() == ',')
    {
        str.pop_back();
    }
    str += ".txt";
```

removing the last character  from the string.

Here is a demonstration program that shows the difference between the above shown approaches.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "File,";

    if (str[str.size() - 1] == ',') str[str.size() - 1] = '\0';

    str += ".txt";

    std::cout << "str.length() = " << str.length() << '\n';

    str = "File,";

    if (str.back() == ',') str.pop_back();

    str += ".txt";

    std::cout << "str.length() = " << str.length() << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
str.length() = 9
str.length() = 8
```

Pay attention to that the character `'\0'` is not outputed if you will try to output the string in the first approach.

Comment: great explanation. Solved my issue. I was not aware of back and pop_back functions of strings before. One question, if I was adding '\0' to the string, the already present '\0' character was still present in the string? and what was being considered when we can concating the strings?

Comment: @M.Jafar An object of the type std::string can contain all characters including the zero character '\0'. If you will append  a string to an existing string the zero character will still present in the middle of the result string.